# How to use Kotlin coroutines await() on main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I just started learning Kotlin coroutines and was trying to simulate some long time API-calls with showing the result on the UI:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun log(msg: String) = println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] $msg")

    override
    fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val resultTV = findViewById(R.id.text) as TextView

        val a = async(CommonPool) {
            delay(1_000L)
            6
        }

        val b = async(CommonPool) {
            delay(1_000L)
            7
        }

        launch(< NEED UI thread here >) {
            val aVal = a.await()
            val bVal = b.await()
            resultTV.setText((aVal * bVal).toString())
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how could I possibly use `launch` method with `main` context.

Unfortunately, I was not able to find anything about delivering results for some specific threads on [the official tutorial for coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#concurrent-using-async).

Comment: Sorry, where did you find `launch` method?

Comment: Maybe this library will help you https://github.com/metalabdesign/AsyncAwait

Comment: I would like through the library, but I just worried is that possible to do using only standard kotlinx.coroutines.

Comment: launch is from kotlinx.coroutines

Comment: Consider nesting `async(UI)` with `async(CommonPool)`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43151714/882912

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**:

Also see [an official example in Kotlin repo](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/android/HandlerContext.kt)

you need to implement [Continuation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#continuation-interface) interface which makes a callback onto Android UI thread and [Coroutine context](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md#coroutine-context)

e.g. (from [here](https://gitlab.com/Starcarr/android-coroutines/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/starcarrlane/coroutines/experimental/Android.kt))

```
private class AndroidContinuation<T>(val cont: Continuation<T>) : Continuation<T> by cont {
    override fun resume(value: T) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) cont.resume(value)
        else Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post { cont.resume(value) }
    }
    override fun resumeWithException(exception: Throwable) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) cont.resumeWithException(exception)
        else Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post { cont.resumeWithException(exception) }
    }
}

object Android : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(ContinuationInterceptor), ContinuationInterceptor {
    override fun <T> interceptContinuation(continuation: Continuation<T>): Continuation<T> =
        AndroidContinuation(continuation)
}
```

Then try:

```
launch(Android) {
    val aVal = a.await()
    val bVal = b.await()
    resultTV.setText((aVal * bVal).toString()) 
}
```

more info:

https://medium.com/@macastiblancot/android-coroutines-getting-rid-of-runonuithread-and-callbacks-cleaner-thread-handling-and-more-234c0a9bd8eb#.r2buf5e6h

Comment: Please refer to the official library for android coroutines -> https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-android/blob/master/coroutines-android/README.md

Comment: Is it from JetBrains or Android team? What do u mean by official?

Answer (score 9):

You shall replace `< NEED UI thread here >` in your code with `UI` context from `kotlinx-coroutines-android` module of [kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines) project. Its usage is explained in the [Guide to UI programming with coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md) with quite a few examples.

Answer (score 4):

First of all include right library designed for Android

***build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android{
...
   dependencies{
      ...
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.19.3"

   }

  kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you are free to use ***UI***

```
suspend private fun getFilteredGList(enumList: List<EnumXXX>) = mList.filter {
    ...
}

private fun filter() {
    val enumList = listOf(EnumX1, EnumX2)
    launch(UI){
        val filteredList = getFilteredList(enumList)
        setMarkersOnMap(filteredList)
    }

}
```

For those that expose project using *kotlin experimental* in `gradle` as ***.aar*** or ***.apk***  to other projects module - Just remember, when You're using kotlin experimental parent modules/project have to accept *kotlin experimental* as well

```
kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Contacts.Intents.UI is now deprecated

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of useful tools that can be used for the purpose of long time running API-calls in `Activity`/`Fragment`. So basically if you want to run two long running tasks in parallel and update UI after both are finished you can do it the next way:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    // launching two tasks in parallel
    val aValDeferred = executeLongRunningTask1Async()
    val bValDeferred = executeLongRunningTask2Async()

    // wait for both of them are finished
    val aVal = aValDeferred.await()
    val bVal = bValDeferred.await()

    // update UI
    resultTV.setText((aVal * bVal).toString())
}

private fun executeLongRunningTask1Async(): Deferred<Int> = lifecycleScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
    delay(1_000L)
    6
}

private fun executeLongRunningTask2Async(): Deferred<Int> = lifecycleScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
    delay(1_000L)
    7
}
```

[`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) -  is a `CoroutineScope`, by default it has `Dispatchers.Main` context, it means we can update UI in the `launch` block. For `LifecycleScope`, use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0` or higher.

`lifecycleScope.async(Dispatchers.Default)` - here `Dispatchers.Default` is used as a context of the coroutine to have the `async` block running in the background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Anko has a wrapper to do it very simply--
see: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Coroutines

```
private fun doCallAsync() = async(UI) {

    val user = bg { getUser() }
    val name = user.await().name
    val nameView = findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView

    nameView.text = name;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be 2.5yrs after the OP's question but it may still help out others in a similar situation.

The original goal can be achieved in a far simpler way than the accepted answer above without the use of async/await (statements 1, 2 and 3 will be executed in sequence, with their associated delays behaving as expected):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    :
    :
    :
    :
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

    val aVal = a()   // statement 1
    val bVal = b()   // statement 2

    resultTV.setText((aVal * bVal).toString())    // statement 3
    }
    :
    :
}

suspend fun a(): Int {
    delay(1_000L)
    return 6
}

suspend fun b(): Int {
    delay(1_000L)
    return 7
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this run statement 3 on the `Dispatchers.Main` thread and not the ui thread?

Comment: @xuiqzy that context corresponds to the UI thread